# Easy (or functional) way to convert a character list to a data frame?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, character

I'm trying to generate a **one column** dataframe from `list.dirs()` that generates a character list like this

```
folders=list.dirs("C:/SIG/PCATA/sig/CETAQUA/Info_cetaqua", recursive = TRUE)
[1] "C:/SIG/PCATA/sig/CETAQUA/Info_cetaqua"                            
[2] "C:/SIG/PCATA/sig/CETAQUA/Info_cetaqua/outputs_client"             
[3] "C:/SIG/PCATA/sig/CETAQUA/Info_cetaqua/outputs_client/Ep1"         
[4] "C:/SIG/PCATA/sig/CETAQUA/Info_cetaqua/outputs_client/Ep1/20130120"
[5] "C:/SIG/PCATA/sig/CETAQUA/Info_cetaqua/outputs_client/Ep1/20130121"
[6] "C:/SIG/PCATA/sig/CETAQUA/Info_cetaqua/outputs_client/Ep2"
```

But when im use `as.data.frame()` function i have a one factor with many levels as result.

As an alternative solution, i tried something like this:

```
folders=data.frame(lapply(folders,as.character),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

But the result is **one row** with as many columns as folders.

I did something wrong, how to fix the problem?

EDIT: I made a little mistake (in bold) that makes it different from the quoted question.

Comment: try `as.data.frame.list(folders)` for a single row

Comment: I correct: I need a column with as many rows as folders, so `as.data.frame.list` does not work in this case, and the duplicate question does not work for me

Comment: In that case just `data.frame(list.dirs(...),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` should work for you

Comment: Thank you! The result is a one column strings dataframe. It's just what I needed ;)

Comment: okay, I reopened